# Is this the place to ask questions about SFML?

Tags: discussion

I see here several questions about OpenGL, but nothing about SFML.
Is it possible to develop this subject here?

Answer (score 2):

This site is more for algorithmic questions than questions about programming in particular. Stack Overflow is already there for questions about some specific code. Though, as you can see on the site, lots of questions about algorithms and techniques do have some code in them. So really, if you're writing graphics algorithms, it shouldn't make any difference what API you're using.